# PHP kill exec() background process after php-fpm restarted

Tags: php, linux, nginx, exec, background-process

I use nginx and php7.1-fpm. I want to run a background process using PHP and exec().

My short code:

```
<?php
exec('/usr/local/bin/program > /dev/null 2>&1');
```

Unfortunately after the **systemd restart php7.1-fpm** the program is killed.

I have tried to run with a different user than the one running the pool:

```
<?php
exec('sudo -u another_user /usr/local/bin/program > /dev/null 2>&1');
```

However, this does not solve the problem - still kills.

I can not use ssh2_connect(). How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you wan the process to survive a system restart?

Comment: Try `exec('/usr/bin/nohup /usr/local/bin/program > /dev/null 2>&1');`

Comment: @TarunLalwani It does not work. :( After php-fpm restart the process is killed.

Comment: I think systemd will reap the child processes on server restart. So not sure if you can really escape that

Comment: @rtfm no, only after php-fpm restart.

Comment: Take a look at that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890855/can-we-reload-one-of-the-php-fpm-pool-without-disturbing-others

Comment: @MohammadTbeishat I want a permanent solution. Eg after php-fpm an update restart will be necessary.

Comment: What are you running, and why don't you just run it as a separate service?

Comment: Post the systemd service file for your php-fpm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is due to the `php-fpm service` being managed by the `systemd`.

All processes launched from `php-fpm` belong to its control-group and when you restart the service `systemd` sends the SIGTERM to all the processes in the control-group even if they are daemonized, detached and/or belong to another session.

You can check your control-groups with this command:

```
systemd-cgls
```

What I've done is to change the KillMode of the `php-fpm` service to process. 
Just edit it's .service file:

```
vi /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/php7.0-fpm.service
```

and change or add the line to the [Service] block:

```
KillMode=process
```

Then reload the configuration by executing:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

That worked for me.

References: 
[Can't detach child process when main process is started from systemd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208782/cant-detach-child-process-when-main-process-is-started-from-systemd)

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.kill.5.html

What would be wonderful would be a command (similar to `setsid`) that allowed to launch a process and detach from control-group but I haven't been able to find it.