# Reloading php-fpm on a production server without affecting current requests

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, server, production

We have a production server with very high specs and to utilize these resources, we want to change the default php-fpm settings like **pm.max_children, pm.max_spare_servers, pm.start_servers, and pm.min_spare_servers**.

We want to apply this change ASAP, but there are **many requests**, and we want to make the change **without causing a mess**.

Can **systemctl reload** command do this without affecting the current requests?
I'm confused about how the reload works actually, will it **wait** until all the active requests finish? in this case, I think we will wait a long time.

Is it safe to use reload command? Are there rather ways to do this task?

**Edit:** I don't trust Chat-GPT yet

Comment: https://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the man page '**systemctl reload php-fpm**' should be what you're looking for :

reload PATTERN...

> Asks all units listed on the command line to reload their
> configuration. Note that this will reload the service-specific
> configuration, not the unit configuration file of systemd. If you
> want systemd to reload the configuration file of a unit, use the
> daemon-reload command. In other words: for the example case of
> Apache, this will reload Apache's httpd.conf in the web server, not
> the apache.service systemd unit file.
> This command should not be confused with the daemon-reload command.

restart PATTERN...

> Stop and then start one or more units specified on the command
> line. If the units are not running yet, they will be started.
> Note that restarting a unit with this command does not necessarily
> flush out all of the unit's resources before it is started again.
> For example, the per-service file descriptor storage facility (see
> FileDescriptoreStoreMax= in systemd.service(5)) will remain intact
> as long as the unit has a job pending, and is only cleared when the
> unit is fully stopped and no jobs are pending anymore. If it is
> intended that the file descriptor store is flushed out, too, during
> a restart operation an explicit systemctl stop command followed by
> systemctl start should be issued.

There's also [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890855/can-we-reload-one-of-the-php-fpm-pool-without-disturbing-others) showing that php-fpm supports graceful restart on SysV systems using the reload option.